# Custom directive interfering with ngClick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpN9b/6/), why does the ngClick in the top link work, but the ngClick in the link to which I have added a custom directive completely fail to function?

```
<a class="regular" ng-click="clickTheLink()">A regular ng-click link</a>
<a class="disableable" disable="disableTheLink" ng-click="clickTheLink()">A disableable link!</a>
```

As far as I can tell, nothing I'm doing in the directive should be interfering at all with ngClick behavior, as all it does is manipulate CSS classes:

```
app.directive('disableable', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: { disable: '&' },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(scope.disable, function (val) {
            if (val){
                elem.addClass('disabled');
                elem.removeClass('enabled');
            }
            else {
                elem.addClass('enabled');
                elem.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, each DOM element only has one scope. So if any directive uses *isolate scope* like you're using here, that becomes the one and only scope on the element. That scope is completely disconnected from any parent scopes, and in your example, `clickTheLink` isn't in there.

The simple answer is to not use isolate scope. It's a real nice syntax but you can do everything it does manually. For the '&' params, you can just use the parse service to parse the attribute expressions.

See updated working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SNQQV/3/

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the statement "each DOM element only has one scope" ... the very nature of prototypical inheritance is that, if you're on a DOM element nested inside 4 controllers, that DOM element can access the scope of any one of it's parents (either naturally via the scope chain, or manually via $parent, or even $rootScope).

Comment: I agree that each DOM element has no more than one scope but I have a different nitpicky point (sorry): If two directives on an element request new scope, one isolate and one not (via scope:true) the element will _not_ have isolate scope.

Comment: @sh0ber This is interesting. If you have `scope:true` (new scope inherited) and `scope:{}` (new isolate scope) both on the same element, it seems to depend on their order. If the isolate scope has higher priority, the whole thing fails with an error. http://jsfiddle.net/s7b7f/10/ If the other way around, it seems the inherited scope still works fine. I think I need to do some more investigation.

Comment: Though, shober, my explanation does seem to explain perfectly why OP's example isn't working. And there's this fiddle, the second link doesn't do anything on click. http://jsfiddle.net/s7b7f/15/

Comment: I agree that your answer correctly identifies the problem otherwise. Note: If the isolate directive either has a higher priority or is declared earlier in the element than the `scope:true` directive, that error is thrown.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea directives could affect each other's scopes like that. It's unfortunate to have to lose the isolate syntax because it is handy and also functions as kind of a nice API for users of the directive.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're creating an isolate scope on line 14 of the fiddle, the clickTheLink function only exists in the controller and not in the directive. While I highly suggest against doing it this way, you can quickly access the parent scope via $parent

```
        <a class="disableable" target="_blank" disable="disableTheLink" ng-click="$parent.clickTheLink()">A disableable link!</a>
```

Putting this code in allows the fiddle to work correctly. Here's the fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/bpN9b/10/

My suggestion would be to look into how ngClass work as well as ngDisabled. I think both of those will allow you to not use this directive at all.